# Email notifications in Spring Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo, spring-webflow, email

I have a web app I am working on  which has admin and basic user levels. There are three entities on the admin level and the basic user is allowed to view or alter just two levels. I would like an email to be sent to the admin user when the basic user tries to delete an entity  entry that is linked to another entity.

Any guidance would be appreciated, I've also been looking at the spring roo in action book

Comment: What is your exact problem: a) how to send an email with java, or b) how to add an any action (like sending an email) that should be performed while deleting an entity in a spring roo application?

Comment: spot on , (option b) is the issue, thanks @Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Copy the (static) delete method of the entity, that is created by roo in the entity aj file, into your entity -- of course you have to fix the compiler problems.

If you have this method in your entity roo will remove it from the generated aj file.

Then you can add additional features in this method, like sending an email.

Comment: sweet thanks, I would give that a go and relay the results, thank you